# Как добавить спереди знак '_' в одинаковых словах?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, файлы

Мой код неправильно работает. Как добавить знак '_' Только перед повторяющимся словами?

Код + тест программы прилагаю ниже.

### 'Данные в файлике:'

```
This is a test
And this is also a test
And these are also tests
test
Это тест
Это также тест
И это также тесты
```

---

### Данные которые нужно получить:

```
This _is _a _test
_And this _is _also _a _test
_And these are _also tests
_test
_Это _тест
_Это _также _тест
И это _также тесты
```

---

Чтение с файла (кодировка Cpp1251):

```
package ua.nure;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Util {
    private static final String ENCODING = "Cp1251";

    public static String readFile(String path) {
        String res = null;
        try {
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
            res = new String(bytes, ENCODING);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(readFile("part1.txt"));
    }
}
```

Мой код:

```
package ua.nure;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Part6 {
    private static final String FILENAME = "part6.txt";

    public static String convert(String input) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w*?\\s", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS + Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(input);

        int current = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            Matcher m2 = p.matcher(stringBuilder.toString());
            while (m2.find()) {
                if (current > 0) {
                    if (m2.group().matches(m.group())) {
                        stringBuilder.replace(m2.start(), m2.end(), "_" + m.group());
                    }
                }
            }
            current++;
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convert(Util.readFile(FILENAME)));
    }
}
```

Comment: [Это не тот же вопрос?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58300062/how-to-change-my-regex-to-match-replace-on-2nd-3rd-words-but-not-on-first/58300477#58300477) Или вы откуда-то тот же текст взяли?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew задание одинаковое, только мне нельзя использовать контейнерные классы. К тому же сделать это всё через считывание с файла. Буду благодарен за вашу помощь!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew я поменял свой код на более понятный, но он всё равно не правильно выводит